# Game loop on redux-saga

Tags: react-native, game-loop, redux-saga

I'm playing with redux-saga to create a version of the [snake game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_(video_game)) in react native, and I'm not sure how to go about the game loop implementation. So far I have a working version, but it feels clunky.. the snake moves at different speeds and the game is not very smooth.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
function *tickSaga() {
  while (true) {
    yield call(updateGameSaga)
    const game = yield select(getGame)
    if (game.crashed)
      break
    yield delay(1000)
  }
}
```

The updateGameSaga basically gets the state from the store, process some logic (finds out if the snake next move will be a crash, move to an empty tile or move to a food tile and grow) and dispatches the corresponding action for it.

I'm slightly aware of things like [requestAnimationFrame](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/timers.html) which I know I should be using, but I'm not sure how to make it work within the saga (maybe I don't need too do it in the saga, hence this question).

Any ideas on how to improve the smoothness of the game loop would be welcome.

#### UPDATE

I've included [redux-saga-ticker](https://github.com/epixode/redux-saga-ticker), which internally uses `setInterval` (code [here](https://github.com/epixode/redux-saga-ticker/blob/master/src/index.js)) to periodically send updates to the channel.

```
function *tickSaga() {
  const channel = Ticker(1000); // game tick every 1000ms
  while (true) {
    yield take(channel);
    yield call(updateGameSaga);

    const game = yield select(getGame)
    if (game.crashed)
      break
  }
}
```

It works better now and I like the channel aproach, but I still feel `requestAnimationFrame` is the way to go, although I'm not yet sure on how to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

How about this.

```
let lastTime = 0;
function *tickSaga() {
  while (true) {
    var time = +new Date();
    var delayTime = Math.max(0, 1000 - (time - lastTime));
    lastTime = time + delayTime;
    yield call(updateGameSaga)
    const game = yield select(getGame)
    if (game.crashed)
      break
    yield delay(delayTime)
  }
}
```

If you need 60 fps, replace 1000 to 16 (1000/60).
For each tick you have a correction of the interval (time - lastTime) so the ticker interval should be uniform.